# How to "overwrite" a previous GPO for specific people using security groups?

Tags: security, group-policy, active-directory

I've created a test domain and created a GPO which restricts write access to all removable media and applied it to the root OU where all my user's will reside. However i know that there will be some people that would need to write to USBs etc eventually (CEO's and IT people mainly)

Trying to work out how to do this with a security group, so if a user is part of a specific security group then that particular GPO won't get applied

Answer (score 1):

Is the GPO setting a Computer setting or a User setting?

If a Computer setting then you can use a Security Group that contains computer accounts as members and add only those computers that you want to apply the policy to as members of the group. Then filter the GPO to apply only to that Security Group.

If a User setting then you can use a Security Group that contains user accounts as members and add only those users that you want to apply the policy to as members of the group. Then filter the GPO to apply only to that Security Group.

You can do the opposite as well and use a Security Group to deny the Group Policy to a group of computers or users.